# Play Framework 2 scala specs2 mockito, how do I write a mocking unit test

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework-2.0, mockito, specs2

So the play framework talks about having specs2 and specs2 having mockito

I want to use mockito to write a test where the template that the controller invokes is a mockito mock.

All the doc's I've found so far are java implementations where you call the mock static function and give it the Mocked class as a generics argument.

From what I can tell the mock function is not exposed by default within a specification, so how do I create a mockito mock?

Please give an example that includes both creating the mock, and asserting the mock is called with certain arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of googling and hair pulling I came up with the following

```
package test

import org.specs2.mutable._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

import org.specs2.mock._
import org.mockito.Matchers

class ToTest {
  def go(a:String) = {
    "other"
  }
}

class MockSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
  "Mock" should {
      "work" in {
        //assemble
        val m = mock[ToTest]
        m.go(anyString) returns "tested"

        //act
        val result = m.go("test")


        //assert
        result must equalTo("tested")
        there was one(m).go(Matchers.eq("test"))
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: worth noting, is that play does not at this time incude the mockito dependency by default.  You need to add it in your Build.scala

Comment: how do you add it to Build.scala?

Comment: Add "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.5" % "test" (or whatever version you prefer) to the appDependencies sequence.